# In search of a tool to help me organize open windows based on tasks

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I've always wanted a product where I can group running programs together. Say I'm working on 3 separate tasks at the same time and I have multiple programs running to facilitate the completion of these tasks. In order to complete the 1st task I have a file explorer window, an instance of notepad, and IE. To complete/monitor the second task I have another instance of notepad, another file explorer window, and a remote desktop session. I would like to be able to group these icons together so that when I swtich between "tasks" i can minimize all windows and restore only the windows that i need to monitor or work on a specific task. Make sense?

Does anybody know of a program or way to accomplish this? I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Stardock tells me their Tiles program will do this. Anybody used it?

Answer (score 1):

You can organize your tasks on different desktops using a [Virtual Desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_desktop) application.

For example, you can run 1st task applications in Desktop 1, then switch to Desktop 2 and run the 2nd task applications, etc. Then, you can switch between your virtual desktops by pressing a hot key.

[VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/) is a free program, and it has a portable version that is only 150k in size.

Comment: Also [Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx) from SysInternals/Microsoft (even smaller at 114 KB only!)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'm gonna give the one from SysInternals a try.

Comment: While most applications implement virtual desktop by simply hiding the windows of some applications on a given desktop and showing others on another desktop, Desktops is using "desktop objects" for each desktop, and this can be limiting. For example, a separate Explorer process must run on each desktop to provide a taskbar and start menu, most tray applications are only visible on the first desktop, and to exit Desktops you need to log off. Also, you cannot move applications from one desktop to the other, as they are bound to the desktop object when they are created.